# Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls NPC conversation / dialogue resetting after starting new game

Tags: diablo-iii, technical-issues, pc, battle.net

**Note:** Sadly, it seems like this is an old bug, dating back at least to 2014, possibly even to 2012.
If you are experiencing this bug, please report it! Hopefully, we will get it fixed soon.

**The problem**

The NPC conversations / dialogue is resetting every time a new game is started (both on Campaign and in Story mode). This is indicated by the blue asterisk reappearing over most (but not always all) NPCs after going through their dialogues.

- A select few dialogues are not resettled. The current state of the game / Passing game checkpoints seems to have something to do with this (needs to be confirmed).
- This problem occurs for all my characters (season and non-season). It has however been reported that this bug may only be present for some characters. Old characters may be less likely to have this bug (needs to be confirmed).
- It has been hypothesised that it could have something to do with some local files (temp/cache) getting cleared or being corrupted (needs to be confirmed).
- Conversations are getting ticked off in the achievements section.

---

**Example**

1. I start act 5, kill the Death Maiden and go to the Survivor's Enclave for the first time.
2. I then klick on all new dialogues, restart the game.

After restarting, all (or most of) the asterisks are back (Tyrael's and  Lorath Nahr's asterisks are **not** back in this particular case).

---

**Does anyone have any idea of what could be the problem?**

If so, is there any temporary fix while waiting for this bug to be fixed?

This bug is especially frustrating in Adventure mode since you restart so often. Each time you start a new game, Tyrael and Orek have their introduction dialogues reset, and after completing a Greater Rift Urshi treats's me as if this is my first completion.

It is not game-breaking, but it is incredibly frustrating. I don't want to click on the dialogues and then cancel them all, on all NPCs, every time I start a new game, to get rid of the asterisks. Nowadays I just leave the asterisk there and check for new dialogues from time to time, but this is not a satisfying solution.

The same is happening to my friend who just bought the game. We both installed the game recently, although I played some D3 vanilla just after release without any problems.

---

> **My system specs:**
>
> - Asus ZenBook UX305 FA
> - Windows 10 64-bit
> - Intel Core M-5Y10c
> - 8 GB RAM
>
> **My friend's system specs:**
>
> - Asus ZenBook UX303 UB
> - Windows 10 64-bit
> - Intel Core i7-6500U
> - 8 GB RAM
>
> Both are running Diablo 3: RoS, build v2.4.2.39192

Comment: Are the conversations still being marked as completed in your challenges menu?

Comment: Yes, the conversations are getting marked and I am getting the achievements, just as you should.

Comment: NOTE: I always got rid of the asterisks, and I didn't restart very often in Story Mode. In the end, I got all the conversation achievements. I don't know, however, if someone's achievement progress would also be reset if one has gone through, let's say half of the conversations, and then restart the game. I might test this. If I do, I will report back.

Answer (score 2):

As far as an answer to your question, there won't be answer except "deal with it" for now.

Most people who play in adventure mode rarely talk to NPC's who aren't a part of rifts, greater rifts or bounties. It's annoying, but you learn to play with the little blue asterisk on your screen.

You'll end up not noticing it after a while and just knowing that it's part of the game forever now.

Comment: Regarding Urshi, Blizzard did specifically report fixing her "My name is Urshi" introduction every time, but I have also noticed the problem eventually coming back :-(